# cant get facebook access token with client credentials but it works with my credentials

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-web-api

Hi guys i am trying to resolve a issue that i have been having for about 2 days now , so i am using the facebook api v3.1 to get access tokens for my website, now it all work good if the clients add me as an admin on there facebook page then i can do the procedure but if i want them to get it them selves i add them as admins on my app on facebook for developer but it does not seem to generate a page token from the long lived token i recieve when they try to login, so it does generate a long lived token but can't seem to get it that they can generate a page token, like i said i have tried making them admins on facebook for developers and still they can't get the page access token but when they make me an admin on there facebook page i can do the whole proccess.
Does anyone know of something that i can try seeing that im running out of options to what i must try next.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: _“i add them as admins on my app on facebook for developer”_ - can you verify they were actually added (confirmed the request they have received), and this is not just still in the “pending invite” state? Did you ask for and did they grant the necessary permission?

Comment: hi @misorude yes i have garuntee that they accepted my request i looked at the graph explorer and saw that on my access token that was generated i have more permissions that the client has so now my next step would be figuring out how to assign the permissions to the client programmatically or even if i can set it it would be awesome but for now im trying just to add the same permisions to the client, do you have any direction for me that i can maybe work to?

Comment: You do not “assign” permissions, you ask the user to grant them - and that is done via the login dialog. (Unless you want your customer to use Graph API Explorer, and have them generate a token there.)

Comment: hmm o di see what you are saying but no i dont want to go to the explorer and grant them permissions i did test it by adding the client access token to the explorer then granted him the permissions then i tried again and then it worked now i just have to do it programmatically do you know of a way that i can grant then the permissions programmatically?

Comment: You can not grant permissions programmatically, you need to implement Facebook Login.

Comment: i have the  login implemented in my website its just if i dont grant them the permissions through the graph explorer then my resopnse from 'https://www.facebook.com/v3.1/dialog/oauth?'
   + 'client_id=' + appId + ''
   + '&redirect_uri=' + encodedUrl + ''
   + '&response_type=token';

Comment: send back a access token that does not have those granted permissions and then my response from
"https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/me/accounts?access_token=" + accessToken; returns as an empty json file which means it did not see the pages for that account... is there maybe a faster way that you know of to grant the permissions then except for the graph explorer?

Comment: Well that’s because you neglected to _ask_ for any permissions there … https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Comment: ok i see what you mean here so would i add this "scope" to the url when i get the user access token or on the request to view the accounts and can you maybe post an axample for me in a case when this "scope" is being used? sorry for all the questions i have just been struggling alot with this because i dont know how to use the scope

Comment: If you create the URL for the login dialog manually, then just add it there as an additional parameter … More details, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login

Comment: ok so  &state={state-param} would then be &state={email,pages_show_list,manage_pages,public_profile} ?

Comment: ive made it like this  const loginUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/v3.1/dialog/oauth?'
   + 'client_id=' + appId + ''
   + '&redirect_uri=' + encodedUrl + ''
   + '&response_type=token' + ''
   + '&state={email,pages_show_list,manage_pages,public_profile}'; but must have done something wrong because im getting a bad request error now LOL

Comment: state and scope are different things …

Comment: ok so which would be the correct one to use and how would i go about it?

Comment: C’mon, that’s really all in the documentation …

Comment: scope: A comma or space separated list of Permissions to request from the person using your app.... so i must uise a scope but i have no idea how to use it neither does the documentation they just tell me the whole time what a scope is but there is no place where it is being used

Comment: i added it like this  + '&scope=email,pages_show_list,manage_pages,public_profile'; will carry on tommorow trying to solve the issue im done for today just getting angry with this facebook api

Comment: got it to work thanks alot for all ur help you really made me come through the day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys hopes this help i fixed my problem by adding the permissions i want granted in a scope in my url then it all worked fine